# Is there a word that means both opening and closing a door?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, hypernyms

As in,

> Please do not *_*_ this door after midnight.

*Operate*? *Move*?

Comment: I suspect that the message is because of noise. Why not address that directly?

Comment: So if the door is closed, you don't want anyone to open it? And if the door is open, you don't want anyone to close it? That seems an odd instruction, but without more context it's hard to say.

Comment: "Don't $#^& with this door after midnight"

Comment: I agree with @tenfour - putting a *reason* on a sign might make people more likely to obey the sign. I can't find it now, but I recall a study where people asked for simple favors, and got better responses when they included a reason - even if the reason was silly. "Excuse me, could I use the copier before you, *because* I need to make some copies." Uh, sure...

Comment: @JohnC: Indeed. [A Google search for `"placebic" copier`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22placebic%22+copier) finds lots of information. (*Placebic* being *placebo* + *-ic*; the idea being that such a "reason" is structured like a reason, and sounds like a reason, but doesn't actually add any information that's not already obvious from the request, so it functions like a placebo.)

Comment: Perhaps WD40 is better than a dictionary in this case?

Comment: Technically, it is always after midnight.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Why would you not just say "**open or close**"?  It's unambiguous, short, and simple. I don't understand why you think you need a *single* word.

**Please do not open or close this door after midnight.**

Comment: anything other than "open or close" would leave me scratching my head as to why they didn't say that.

Comment: @nohat: "Please do not use this door after midnight" would leave you scratching your head?

Comment: @Robusto We can't tell if that's what the OP meant. "Use" can also mean *walk through* which might be allowed.

Comment: Well, this isn't augury or holy scripture. Far too much attention has been devoted to this question already, and now we're supposed to treat this as some kind of sacred text?

Comment: @Robusto If the door was already open, "Please do not use..." would mean, please do not walk through it.  It's basically asking for someone else be helpful and close it.

Comment: @Robusto, yes, to me, using a door would mean to pass through it. Opening and closing a door are separate actions from using a door, in my mind.

Comment: @Izkata: No it's not.

Comment: In my mind, the problem with this statement is that the reader is left wondering what state the door ought to be in if it can't be closed or opened. I *know* that sounds ridiculous, but really I think "Do not *touch* this door* is the perfect conveyance of the OP's intent.

Answer (score 29):

I like *operate* or just *use*.

Comment: I'd say "operate" is best; "use" could also mean walking through the door.

Comment: @tenfour: "Use" is what most people would say if they didn't overthink it. The normal use case (!) for door opening and closing involves going through it, especially when someone considers forbidding such an action.

Comment: If I read a sign that says "do not use this door after midnight", I would think I should not go through it.

Comment: If you're not supposed to open or close it, I can't image you would be going through it. I definitely agree that **"use"** seems to be the best choice.

Comment: Depending on just what the OP had in mind. He says he wants "do not open or close". So if the door was left open, someone shouldn't close it? If that's what he means, then "use" could be misleading. If I saw a sign saying "Do not use this door after midnight" and it was sitting open, I might think they want me to close it so no one can "use" it.

Comment: If the door is already open, then it would all right to walk through it. So "use" isn't right.

Comment: There is a big difference here between *operate* and *use*.  Few people would think passing through a door is *operating* it, so I have no particular quarrel with that answer.  But *many* people would consider passing through as one of the actions included in *using* a door. If OP means that passing (silently) through an already open door is fine, then "do not use" would absolutely be the wrong thing to say.

Comment: use works for me!

Answer (score 15):

As an alternative to the other answers:

> Please do not ***touch*** this door after midnight.

Comment: I think this takes it beyond what the OP is looking for.  It would probably work in a small environment with a limited population.  But if you have an unfamiliar population interacting regularly then the warning could be misconstrued, especially if the door is a large door with a remote opener.

Comment: @Chad: Actually, we are not sure what the OP is looking for. (As of this writing, he has not responded to several comments suggesting that clarification would be helpful.) But point taken that, depending on the door, you could open or close it without touching it. I still think this is a much better single-word answer than *use*, if we are to take the OP's question at face value.

Answer (score 7):

Swinging after midnight not allowed?

Comment: Apparently you don't know the definition of [swinging](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swinging).

Comment: @zzzzBov: I suspect he knew the meaning.  Charlie, thanks for the chuckle.

Answer (score 4):

> This door must not be used after midnight.

Or,

> This door is not to be used after midnight.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/a/60373/2303

Answer (score 4):

Since we seem to be implying there is a detriment to operating/using/toggling the door why not specifically ask the person not to incur the detriment: "Please don't creak the door after midnight!!"  Just enumerate the negative effect as the action to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say ***swing*** in that case

Answer (score 1):

What about *displace*, *manipulate*, *interact with* or *tamper with*?