# What does a door do on its hinge?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, collocation

In general sense of the language we would say that a door "*opens*" or "*closes*". But I am looking for a one-word answer (*preferably*) that would indicate its motion around the *hinge*. Does it *swivel*, *swerve*, *flap*? (*you get the idea*)

**NOTE:** I am not talking about spin doors that revolve or sliding doors, just the conventional ones with hinge(s).

And, please go through the entire question. This is not a duplicate of *[What does the door do?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/what-does-the-door-do)* or *[Is there a word that means both opening and closing a door?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60372/is-there-a-word-that-means-both-opening-and-closing-a-door?rq=1)*

Comment: I was glad to see an O.P. add some extra links to a question, showing that some research time had indeed been invested before asking the question.

Comment: Usually squeaks.

Comment: @BillFranke: A door *squeaks* open, agreed. But, it never "squeaks" on its hinges! Unless we are talking bout a very rusty hinge ;)

Comment: @KeyBrd Basher: Yes, I was thinking of very rusty hinges and doors in tales of murder and mystery. Okay, to be technically correct, I suppose one must say "The door swung squeakily on its hinges", but many writers would find that too long and boring a sentence for the average mystery book reader. That's why they say things like "The door squealed on its hinges" and "every door shrieked on its hinges" [Check those phrases out on Google]. Even the doors in my apartment squeak.

Comment: @BillFranke: I think the word to be used will change with the context( See J.R.'s answer).

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher: Yes, J.R. & I agree on that point about context being the deciding factor. Almost everyone here would agree with that, I'm sure.

Comment: I thought a door was said to *hang* by its *hinges* — if that no longer sounds redundant.

Comment: @tchrist: I am looking for some........................*action*, if you may. "Hanging on the hinges" to me seems kind of *inactive*.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The door [*swings*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swing#Verb) on its hinge.

> To move backward and forward, especially rotating about or hanging from a fixed point.

*Turns*, as suggested by other answerers, sounds like another great possibility. But a quick look at the actual usage stats brings up something interesting.

Here are the top 50 collocations for "the door [v*]" from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

```
     |   COCA             |   BNC
     |                    |
 1   |   OPENED     992   |   WAS        402
 2   |   WAS        943   |   OPENED     327
 3   |   OPEN       830   |   OPEN       175
 4   |   IS         659   |   CLOSED     151
 5   |   OPENS      611   |   SHUT       103
 6   |   SHUT       588   |   IS          73
 7   |   CLOSED     573   |   SWUNG       57
 8   |   SWUNG      249   |   HAD         53
 9   |   CLOSES     164   |   SLAMMED     42
10   |   HAD        158   |   LEADING     21
11   |   SLAMMED    137   |   OPENS       21
12   |   LEADING     98   |   WOULD       20
13   |   SLAMS       92   |   BURST       19
14   |   WOULD       88   |   'S          19
15   |   SLID        80   |   LOCKED      19
16   |   'S          71   |   WILL        18
17   |   LOCKED      66   |   FLEW        17
18   |   FLEW        63   |   WERE        16
19   |   CREAKED     57   |   BEING       13
20   |   CLOSE       56   |   SLID        13
21   |   SWINGS      50   |   HAS         11
22   |   HAS         49   |   BANGED      11
23   |   SHUTS       49   |   CLICKED     11
24   |   CLICKED     46   |   MADE        10
25   |   SLAM        45   |   CLOSE        9
26   |   UNLOCKED    43   |   CRASHED      9
27   |   BURST       40   |   MUST         9
28   |   BANGED      40   |   DID          8
29   |   WEARING     39   |   SAYING       8
30   |   SAID        36   |   CREAKED      7
31   |   CRACKED     34   |   CAN          7
32   |   DID         34   |   LOOKING      7
33   |   WERE        34   |   SHUTS        7
34   |   WILL        34   |   BEGAN        6
35   |   CAME        30   |   CLOSES       6
36   |   ARE         29   |   OPENING      6
37   |   STOOD       28   |   STOOD        6
38   |   LOOKING     25   |   WENT         6
39   |   COULD       23   |   FELL         5
40   |   BEING       22   |   BROKE        5
41   |   DOES        21   |   CAME         5
42   |   GAVE        21   |   HISSED       5
43   |   BURSTS      20   |   MIGHT        5
44   |   CLOSING     20   |   SLAM         5
45   |   CRASHED     20   |   SWINGING     5
46   |   FLIES       20   |   UNLOCKED     5
47   |   REMAINED    19   |   WO           5
48   |   CAN         18   |   CLANGED      4
49   |   HIT         18   |   FACING       4
50   |   COMES       16   |   INTERRUPTED  4
```

As you can see, out of these *swing* is the top (and arguably only) verb that fits your bill, while *turn* is not even on the list.

Comment: Oh, I really like **creaks** – even if that might be only [temporal](http://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/2011/6/29/72f4f98d-a5b8-420b-89c3-6895dbf2c748.png).

Comment: ".....and the door *swung* open". Seems more like it. Good answer!

Answer (score 10):

If *turns* is too bland for you, you could say that it [***pivots***](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22pivots+on+the+hinge%22&oq=%22pivots+on+the+hinge%22&gs_l=hp.3...1521.5230.0.5501.21.20.0.0.0.0.141.2064.11j9.20.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.oCL4u9I_S6Y&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=9c1c7a74a90eb2f8&bpcl=38897761&biw=1459&bih=736) on the hinge.

Picking the "right" word depends much on your context, too.

*"The door swung open"* is indeed a very natural way to indicate the movement. However, if you were to, say, describe the appartus of an experiment in a scientific journal, *swing* might not be the best verb to use; something more "formal" like *pivot* may work better.

Then again, there's *turn*, which can be a very apt word in a metaphor, much like Wouk's metaphor quoted in Malvolio's answer to your question.  In that context, I think *turn* works much better than *swing* or *swivel*.

Then there's *flap*, which you offered in your question. I think that would work best if you were describing a loose shutter in a strong wind.

> The shutter *turned* in the wind.
>   The shutter *swung* in the wind.
>   The shutter *swiveled* in the wind.
>   The shutter *flapped* in the wind.

Which do you think sounds best?

Comment: Yes, the whole debate - er - is predicated on context. It's not a/n - er - clear-cut case.

Answer (score 3):

It just *turns* on its hinge.  Sorry.

> The story begins with Willie Keith because the event turns on his personality as the massive door of a vault turns on a small jewel bearing. -- *The Caine Mutiny* Herman Wouk

Comment: _Just?_ If a door can turn on a hinge, it can surely _swivel_ on a hinge, too.

Comment: wouldn't it seem as if "*turns*" is being used here to exhibit a metaphor.........

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher: It seems the metaphor is more with the vault door, not strictly with the verb "turns". _Turns_ is a very viable answer to your question, I think.

Comment: @J.R. Really?? I thought the author was drawing a parallel b/w the *events* and *vault door*, and the subject's *personality* and *jewel bearing*. Although, I totally agree with **turns** being a possible answer to my question. Just not convinced with the example provided.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher: I think we're in agreement, then. I only meant to point out that the metaphorical usage here would not preclude "turn" from being a valid answer to the question "What does a door do on its hinge?"

Comment: @J.R.: Hopefully, but not always in my experience, "remain".

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher - to be hyper-technical, it's a *simile* because it's a direct comparison.

Comment: @Malvolio: Totally agree!

Answer (score 1):

The door could be said to [*articulate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/articulate#Verb) on the hinge.

Comment: It would be helpful to add a reference to this definition.

Comment: @joulesm *articulate* is well-defined and fits the bill -- just that it may or may not suit OP's context.

Comment: @Kris good point. I only meant that an example of its usage or definition would also be helpful for the OP.

Comment: Can you provide an example, illustrating its usage.

Answer (score -2):

> The door rests on its hinges.

Well, that's what I would say!

Comment: The question specifically asks about the motion of a door around its hinges. Clearly, the door cannot be resting when it is moving.

Comment: The door is permanently resting on hinges, if the door is swung open it is moving while on the hinges - but were it not still resting on the hinges, well the door would fall over.

Comment: We don't use *resting* to **indicate its motion**; it simply signifies here the manner in which the door is attached.